# Django Local Font

Tags: python, django

I can't connect fonts stored in the static/fonts folder. The path itself django as far as I understand sees, but the font is not loaded on the site

static/css/main.css:

```
.container {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: url("../fonts/font-light.ttf");
}
```