# how to upload custom font w/ django project

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-staticfiles

I am working on a project w/ Django and I am having trouble with fonts. I am able to see the uploaded font on my computer but not on my phone.

This is my file path:

```
static
 |
 interface
  |
  main.css
  folsom-black.otf
```

This is my code for my html file:

```
    <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Folsom';
      src:
           url("{% static 'interface/folsom-black.otf' %} format('otf')");
    }
    </style>
```

This is the code for my css file:

```
    @font-face {
       font-family: 'Folsom';
       src:
         url('../interface/folsom-black.otf') format('otf');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72265784/using-custom-font-in-django-css) post might help you out! I am not a professional in Django myself but see if this helps you out!